# Concating values from configMap and secret

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, configmap, kubernetes-secrets

I have a configMap file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  labels:
    owner: testdb
  name: testdb-configmap 
data:
  host: postgres
  port: "5432"
```

and a secret file:

```
aapiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
type: Opaque
metadata:
  labels:
    owner: testdb
  name: testdb-secret
  namespace: test
data:
  user: dGVzdA==
  pwd: dGVzdA==
```

and I want to build an environment variable `CONNECTION_STRING` as below:

```
env:
 - name: CONNECTION_STRING
   value: "Host=<host-from-configmap>;Username=<user-from-secret>;Password=<password-from-secret>;Port=<port-from-configmap>;Pooling=False;"
```

I want to know if this is possible and if yes, then how? I have also looked at using `.tpl` (named templates) but couldn't figure out a way.

---

**NOTE**

Since I don't have access to the image which requires `CONNECTION_STRING` I have to build it this way. These configmap and secret files are also going to remain like this.

---

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Kubernetes can [set environment variables based on other environment variables](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-environment-variable-container/#using-environment-variables-inside-of-your-config).  This is a core Kubernetes Pod capability, and doesn't depend on anything from Helm.

Your value uses four components, two from the ConfigMap and two from the Secret.  You need to declare each of these as separate environment variables, and then declare a main environment variable that concatenates them together.

```yaml
env:
  - name: TESTDB_HOST
    valueFrom:
      configMapKeyRef:
        name: testdb-configmap # {{ include "chart.name" . }}
        key: host
  - name: TESTDB_PORT
    valueFrom:
      configMapKeyRef:
        name: testdb-configmap
        key: port
  - name: TESTDB_USER
    valueFrom:
      secretKeyRef:
        name: testdb-secret
        key: user
  - name: TESTDB_PASSWORD
    valueFrom:
      secretKeyRef:
        name: testdb-secret
        key: password
  - name: CONNECTION_STRING
    value: Host=$(TESTDB_HOST);Username=$(TESTDB_USER);Password=$(TESTDB_PASSWORD);PORT=$(TESTDB_PORT);Pooling=False;
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked.

Comment: For others coming here after me, it's actually configMapKeyRef and not configMapRef in the yaml.

Comment: Fixed.  (Feel free to use the [edit] link to make technical corrections like this.)

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe what you're asking to do is possible.

Furthermore, do not use configs maps for storing information like this. It's best practice to use secrets and then mount them to your container as files or ENV variables.

I would abandon whatever you're thinking and re-evaluate what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: As you can see I am not using configmap for anything sensitive, I have a secret file for that. I can mount individual values to ENV variables but needed to concat them into one value.

Comment: You are correct. I misread conflated the configmap and secrets.